# css unset not working in chrome, fine in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm working on a responsive layout with the following css:

```
#page_container {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    padding:0;
    height: 190px;
}
#logo_image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: -10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
#logo_image {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;     
    max-height: 150px;
    top:0px;
    left: unset;
}
```

The idea is that below 960 px in width the logo image should be smaller and centered. This is working fine in firefox, but in chrome the "left: unset;" is not being processed and the image is appearing far to the left of center.

I am not aware of any compatibility issues with unset and in fact use it elsewhere on the page without problems. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unset is not supported in Chrome:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Use auto instead.

### Update (Feb 2016)

Chrome now supports `unset` as of version 41.

Comment: Is there a better way? Odd that another unset on the same page is working fine.

Comment: Ok try setting left to auto.

Answer (score 1):

'unset' was previously unsupported in Chrome, but it is now supported. The example now works similarly in Chrome and Firefox.

Chromium has supported 'unset' since December 2014:
https://codereview.chromium.org/775153002